# Spring Boot on Wildfly is ignoring my Logback settings

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly, logback, mybatis

I'm developing a Spring Boot 2.1 application which run on Wildfly 14 and use MyBatis.
But I have a problem with logging: Spring is ignoring my logback-spring.xml configuration file and I'm unable to log MyBatis query.

I've tryed to change settings on application.properties but seems that Spring always use the default settings (I can see standard logs at boot).

This is my pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>



<!-- Package as an executable jar -->
<build>
    <finalName>SpringApp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is my application.properties

```
# logging
logging.level.root=ERROR
```

And this is my logback-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.core " level="error" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.beans" level="error" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.context" level="error" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.transaction" level="error" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="error" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.test" level="error" />
    <logger name="*" level="error"/>
</configuration>
```

I always see INFO logs, for instance. And every MyBatis settings I've tryed dosn't work.

Comment: Seems that the problem is also in _application.properties_ file because you say that your project log message in INFO level, so the properties *logging.level.root=ERROR* is not correctly loaded. I suppose that the context is not correctly loaded. Can you publish your code?

Comment: Do you need the standalone.xml file? Or the entire application.properties?